# Python code to filter logfile by a specific time

Tags: python, file, filter, android-logcat

I've run into an issue while coding the next code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def find_last_index(file_rec):
    time = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2)
    file_content = file_rec
    while True:
        ind = file_content.find(time.strftime("%m-%d"))
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(file_content[ind:13], '%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        if time.hour > date_obj.hour:
            file_content = file_content[ind+5:]
            ind = file_content.find("12-22", ind)
            return ind
        else:
            file_content = file_content[ind + 1:]


file_name = raw_input("Enter File Path From this file's dir: ")
read_file = open(file_name, 'r')
content = read_file.read()
read_file.close()
lastindex = find_last_index(content)
print content[:lastindex]
content = input()
write_file = open("ResultFile.txt", "w")
write_file.write(content[:lastindex])
write_file.close()
```

The code is supposed to take a log-file looks like that:

```
12-22 20:14:15.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.974 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.974 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.974 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-22 20:14:15.9
```

Each line starts with the date and time.  I would like to insert into a new file only the statements from 2 hours ago until the current time. 
It would be awesome if someone would help me to solve it.

Comment: How is your code not working? What output/errors is it producing? What do you expect to see instead?

Comment: my output should be the only statements between two hours of the debug time. After i debug the code the file stays the same and when i tried to print the result instead of writing it into the file it printed nothing.

Comment: `NullPointerException` is a Java error, this is Python.

Comment: the log file I've showed is a java log file all i want to do with python is to edit this file as i wrote above

Comment: Do lines start with dates, like 12-22, or times, like 20:14:15?

Comment: When I run your code on the given data, it faults on the first line, unable to detect a date in the given format: **ind** comes back as -1.

Comment: Is the file format consistent enough that you could deal with this line-by-line?  I fear that you're using a large amount of memory that will make this slow and harder to debug.

Answer (score 1):

I can't resist suggesting the use of the **arrow** module for manipulating dates. In many cases it makes life easier. Heres what I offer.

```
>>> import arrow
>>> refTime = arrow.now().shift(hours=-2).strftime('%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> refTime
'12-27 13:13:57'
>>> str(refTime)
'12-27 13:13:57'
>>> refTime_as_str = str(refTime)
>>> with open('logfile.txt') as log:
...     for line in log:
...         if line[:len(refTime_as_str )] >= refTime_as_str:
...             print (line.strip())
...             
12-27 15:45:50.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.972 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.973 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.974 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.974 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
12-27 15:45:50.974 26560 27796 D Robocol : no packet received: NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it by reverse-engineering your code logic.

Your function **find_last_index** continually updates its local copy of the input file.  Eventually, it returns the index of the first entry that's at least two (truncated) hours old -- but it's the index *in that local copy*.  Up until you find that time, you're chopping off 5-character dates and then individual characters, so you eventually get an index that's less than 20.

Back in the main program, you still have the original data, kept in variable **content**.  You apply the **ind** index returned from your routine, an index that no longer applies to **content**.

If you want to retain your current logic flow, then either

- return **file_content** to the main program, or
- instead of deleting the front of **file_content** on each failed iteration, update **ind** and start your search from that point.

Possible code change:

```
ind = file_content[ind:].find(time.strftime("%m-%d"))
date_obj = datetime.strptime(file_content[ind:ind+13], '%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```